# I can't install the "numba" package via "pip"

Tags: python, pip, numba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNs0A.png)

I can't install the "numba" package via "pip". I want to install the "numba" package, but an error appears every time

Comment: IS your python env is Python 3.6 or later, and Numpy versions 1.15 or later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check your python and numpy version . Numba is compatible with Python 3.6 or later, and Numpy versions 1.15 or later. Please check the documentation
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/installing.html

Answer (score 2):

Installing using pip on x86/x86_64 Platforms
Binary wheels for Windows, Mac, and Linux are also available from PyPI. You can install Numba using pip:

$ pip install numba